# How to implement 303 redirect?

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I'd like to know how to implement 303 redirect for displaying `post` data.

Example:

```
I send the form.

Redirect

Page displays the info I just posted. (Eg: Name, email).
```

I think it is done with parameters, like `/index.php?name=TheName&email=theEmail` but i'm not sure, since I've tried to find some good article explaining it but couldn't.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Daedalus Hi, I didn't tried yet, because I prefer to inform better first. I just saw articles, wikipedia etc, about what does the 303 redirect and why it's recommended, but didn't see a code example, on how to retrieve data. I didn't say that isn't viable, just want to know hows the way it's meant to be. Thanks

Comment: So to make sure I understand you, @Jorge, you want to retrieve information sent by a form, but the method of sending it doesn't matter(aside from it being POST, that is)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In PHP you can perform a 303 redirect using  `header()`:

```php
header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: http://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']/new/location/here");
```

The problem you may face is retaining the form information after the redirect. One solution might be using [PHP session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) to store the form data.

You could redirect using parameters to pass the submitted data, but that isn't what I'd consider a 'clean' solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it other ways rather then passing the parameters in the url.

1. Send the form.
2. After checking valid values, Store the result in a database, session as you would normally do.
3. Redirect
4. Retrieve from the database or session.
5. **Use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on the output.**